# VF Page Error Message in Production

Tags: visualforce, contact

Years ago I wrote a VF page and a controller class to edit all contacts of an agreement in one form. The user can select contacts, their role and set a primary contact. If user clicks submit button some lines of Javascript/JQuery store all values as JSON string in a hidden field. The controller class just needs this JSON string to change the list of contacts.

[image: Edit Contact Roles 1]
[image: Edit Contact Roles 2]

That worked even with Lightning. Since some months I get an error message when clicking the add button to add one or more empty dropdowns (for lookup popup) for new contacts. The form is used not often, so I cannot say how long this error occurs. The message says:

**The name can only contain underscores and alphanumeric characters. It must begin with a letter and be unique, and must not include spaces, end with an underscore, or contain two consecutive underscores.**

First I guessed some variable name in my code is wrong, but I didn't change the code this year.

But maybe it is a wrong filename like in this question:
https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000lOWxQAM
Name of VF page is edit_contact_roles.page, controller class is EditContactRoles.cls and ContactRoleCRItem.cls for a helper class which only holds some data for each contact.
JQuery is included with:

```
<script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.PBSI__jQuery_1_8_2,'')}" />
```

Biggest problem is that the error only occurs in production, I cannot reproduce it in sandbox, I deployed current sandbox code to production, but the error still occurs.

Does anyone knows what this message means and how to fix it?

Buttons on VF page:

```
<apex:selectList value="{!nrows}" size="1">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
</apex:selectList>
<apex:commandButton value="Add Rows" action="{!addRows}" />
<apex:commandButton value="cancel" action="{!cancel}" />
<apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!submit}" id="submitCRForm"/>
```

Controller code for add button creates n new contact items:

```
public PageReference addRows() {
        this.addNewContactRoles();
        
        PageReference nextPage = new PageReference('/apex/edit_contact_roles/?pageId=' + this.pageId);
        nextPage.setRedirect(true);
        return null;    
    }
    
    @TestVisible
    private void addNewContactRoles() {
        if (this.formData != null && this.formData != '') {
            this.contactRolesList = (List<ContactRoleCRItem>) System.JSON.deserialize(this.formData, List<ContactRoleCRItem>.class);
        }
        
        if (this.nrows == null || this.nrows == 0) {
            this.nrows = 1;
        }
        
        Boolean isPrimary = (this.contactRolesList.size() == 0);
        
        for (Integer i = 0; i < this.nrows; i++) {
            this.contactRolesList.add(new ContactRoleCRItem(ID_NULL, isPrimary, ID_NULL, '', '', false));   
            isPrimary = false;
        }   
    }
```

Helper class ContactRoleCRItem just holds some data for each contact and has no logic.

Comment: Can you post the code for `Add Rows` button. I suspect the VF page url might not be forming well. Also can you paste a screenshot of the page name ? Or right click and press `inspect element` (chrome) to check what is the VFPage url being formed. And share a screenshot.

Comment: added some code and screenshot

Comment: Can uou try changing this `PageReference nextPage = new PageReference('/apex/edit_contact_roles/?pageId=' + this.pageId);` to `PageReference nextPage = new PageReference('/apex/edit_contact_roles?pageId=' + this.pageId);`. Also, when you click addRows, the network tab in chrome will show the VF page url being formed, can you share that too?

Comment: I changed the PageReference from edit_contact_roles/?pageId= to edit_contact_roles?pageId= and deployed it. But error still occurs in production, sandbox works.
The Javascript warning occurs on several Salesforce apges and seems not to be related to my code.

Comment: Ok give another try by removing the page params from `?` and add it via `pageRef.getParameters().put('Key', 'Value');` or if possible can you try with a page with no underscore at all.

Comment: yep, I added pageId by put() method and changed page name to editContactRoles, now it works! Seems that page name with underscores caused the error: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155078/name-error-in-visualforce-page 
But error message says that name can contain undercsores, maybe just one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with trial and error we came up with an answer to change the page name without any `underscore` and it worked.

Not sure though why page name with `underscore` worked in sandbox and not in production.  (If anyone has an explanationto this do comment it.)